# Using randomColor in R 4.0.3 + shiny 1.6.0

Tags: r, shiny

When using `randomColor()` in  R 4.0.3 + shiny 1.6.0

```
library(shiny)
library(randomcoloR)

ui <- fluidPage( plotOutput( "plot1" ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(
    plot( 1, 1, col = randomColor())
    )  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get the error message:

```
Warning: Error in context_eval: <string conversion failed>   
193: <Anonymous>
```

I don't have the issue in R, this code works fine:

```
library(randomcoloR)
plot( 1, 1, col = randomColor())
```

Comment: I don't get an error and `colA = randomColor(1)` works as expected changing colors randomly on every click.

Comment: What exactly does the error say that you are getting?

Comment: Huh. I get "Error: <string conversion failed>"

Comment: it works (with R 3.3.2), not reproducible

Comment: I'm on R 4.0.3 so I guess that could be it? Would be nice to know why it doesn't work for me though.

Comment: I confirm I get an error on R 4.0.3, shiny 1.6.0, randomcoloR 1.1.0.1 : `Warning: Error in context_eval: <string conversion failed>
  193: <Anonymous>`

Comment: I submitted an [issue on github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3289)

Comment: Hi @rhub, Do you also use R on windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm on windows 10 and I'm using shiny 1.6.0. Thanks for submitting the issue to github.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3289#issuecomment-965085617) it's been fixed in Shiny V8 3.6.0

Updating package from CRAN should solve your problem